# Getting TypeError: conv.parameters in not a function at app.intent with Dialogflow fufillment

Tags: dialogflow-es, chatbot

I am trying to learn more about Dialogflow fulfilment and I am following the tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=biN00SoMRI8) on youtube.

When I deploy and test I get an empty response back in the chatbot. I can see the following error:
TypeError:conv.parameters is not a function at app.intent (/srv/index.js:24:23)

Would someone be able to help we find where I am going wrong. Code is below:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const {dialogflow}=require('actions-on-google')

const WELCOME_INTENT = 'Default Welcome Intent'
const FALLBACK_INTENT = 'Default Fallback Intent'
const Dept_ENTITY= 'DEPTChoice'
const Dept_INTENT='DEPT'


const app = dialogflow()

app.intent(WELCOME_INTENT, (conv) => {
    conv.ask("Hi! I am a test bot - what department are you in?")
})

app.intent(FALLBACK_INTENT, (conv) => {
    conv.ask("huh?")
})

app.intent(DEPT_INTENT, (conv) => {
  const dept_type=conv.parameters('DEPTChoice').toLowerCase()
  if (dept_type == "Sales") {
  conv.ask("Great Sales")
  } else   conv.ask("Great - Your in Sales")

})

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest(app)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as the error message says, [`conv.parameters`](https://actions-on-google.github.io/actions-on-google-nodejs/2.12.0/classes/_service_dialogflow_conv_.dialogflowconversation.html#parameters) is not a function.

It is a JavaScript object, where the object properties are the names of the parameters. So your line could be written as

```
const dept_type = conv.parameters['DEPTChoice'].toLowerCase();
```

Note the use of square brackets `[]` to reference a property on the object, rather than parenthesis `()` to do a function call. It could be that this was just difficult to see in the video.